# Edit image in asp.net mvc

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have saved an image in the uploads folder and its path in SQL Server. When I click on the edit button it should show the uploaded image and when I chose a new image it should delete the existing image file and upload the new one.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header">
    <h5 class="card-title text-uppercase">add new</h5>
</div>
<div class="card-body">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "ImageSlider", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Id)
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ImagePath)
            <div class="custom-file">
                <input type="file" name="postedFile" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">
                <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <img src="@Url.Content(Model.ImagePath)" alt="@Model.ImageName" class="img-thumbnail" width="100" height="100" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary rounded-0 text-uppercase">Upload</button>
            <a href="@Url.Action("List","ImageSlider")" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary rounded-0 text-uppercase"><i class="fas fa-backward"></i> Back to List</a>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Here is my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("Edit/{id}")]
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        var slider = db.ImageSliders.Find(id);
        if (slider == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(slider);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Route("Edit/{id}")]
    public ActionResult Edit(ImageSlider imageSlider)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(imageSlider).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("List", "ImageSlider");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: What do you need help with?

Comment: I want to edit existing image file and replace it with new upload in edit view

Comment: Sure, but what isn't working for you with the code you have posted?

Comment: when i click on edit button it redirect me edit view. 1- It does not have image selected. 2 When i choose image and click on update it does not insert new image path and does not replace exiting one. Thank you if you help me out

Comment: Other than edit i have done all the functionality like retrieve insert details delete here the code sample https://github.com/farhan1386/CarouselSlider_Demo